# Do support gems link all, or just nearby gems?

Tags: path-of-exile

If you have an item with 4 sockets, that are linked like so:

1--2--3--4

does that mean that a support gem in 1 would be supporting all gems (so in sockets 2,3,4), or just the one in socket 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gems would support all other linked gems.

In your example that would result in gems 2, 3 and 4 being supported.

You can also put multiple support gems in an item to have the combined effects on a skill.

An example: gem 1 is a Lesser multiple projectile gem, gem 2 is an extra fire damage gem, gem 3 is a fireball gem and gem 4 is a spectral throw gem.(I'm not saying this is a good combo)
This will result in:

- a spectral throw with extra fire damage and three projectiles
- a fireball skill with extra fire damage and three projectiles

Comment: Check! And as a result of that, trying to get an extra link 4--1 ("all the way around") will be utterly useless, as it would amount to the same thing. thanks!

Comment: @Nanne It would also be impossible. There is no such thing as a "connection loop"

Comment: Yes, but you can imagine a noob trying to hit that sweet spot by reforging (read: wasting items) the links :). So thanks for stopping me from trying that :)